# (407) Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )

Tags: vb.net, web-services, proxy

I am getting an error when my application tries to communicate with a web service

(407) Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )

I saw a few topics but I could not understand. I am using VB.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.config file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I think the error referring to `TraceUtility` is unrelated - different problem.

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, your proxy server is preventing access to the service. You can either write some code to ask the user for credentials for the proxy, or (easier) you can put the following in your applications app.config:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
<system.net>
```

There are other settings if you have more complex requirements. Try here for guidance

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09361bca

Comment: thanks for the reply. I could understand a little more, but by putting this snippet in my app.config file, I get another error:

The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.

Of course, I do not know if I'm entering in the correct place:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
  </system.net>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>